# Try to find recent high index

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to find the highest candle index (not value) for last 25 days when macdLine and signalLine cross.

```
//@version=5

indicator("top finder 25 days ago", overlay=true)
[macdLine, signalLine, _] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
var int MyHighestIndex = na

// when macdLine and signalLine cross and -4.1
if ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) and macdLine < -4.1
    MyHighestIndex := ta.highestbars(high, 25)
label.new(MyHighestIndex, high, "high", yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_arrowdown)
```

I always get the study Error: Error on bar 11737: Bar index value of the 'x' argument (0.0000) in 'label.new()' is too far from the current bar indext try to use 'time' instdea.

Thanks for helping

I've tried to make a take-profit for with the last recent high from his middle value.`your text`

Answer (score 0):

`ta.highestbars()` will return the offset with a negative number. This offset is from the current candle. So, you shouldn't use it directly in your `label.new()`. Instead, combine it with `bar_index`.

```
label.new(bar_index + MyHighestIndex, high, "high", yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_arrowdown)
```

Comment: Now I have no error but the code still not good, it's not give me the top of the 25 days period